# How to add new columns to a timeseries based on the matching of day/date with an expected pattern?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a timeseries that is supposed to have values of a specific observable on even days (aka Monday, Wednesday, and Saturday).

```
             0           1
0     Saturday  03/23/2024
1    Wednesday  03/20/2024
2       Monday  03/18/2024
3     Saturday  03/16/2024
4    Wednesday  03/13/2024
..         ...         ...
```

I would like to add two new columns to this time series with boolean values. The first additional column is checking whether any specific day is following a succession of Monday/Wednesday/Saturday meaning any day is sandwiched by two different days in ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Saturday"]? The second column is checking whether the time differences between any day with the previous one is in [2, 3] given the dates? How to implement these functionalities into two separate new columns?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if it's what you want

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    0: ['Saturday', 'Wednesday', 'Monday', 'Saturday', 'Wednesday'],
    1: ['03/23/2024', '03/20/2024', '03/18/2024', '03/16/2024', '03/13/2024']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1])

# Calculate the day of the week for each date to confirm it matches the day mentioned in column 0
df['Day_of_week'] = df[1].dt.day_name()

# Check if the day is correctly placed between two different days in the specified sequence
valid_days = ['Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Saturday']
df['Valid_succession'] = df[0].shift(1).isin(valid_days) & df[0].shift(-1).isin(valid_days) & (df[0].shift(1) != df[0].shift(-1))

# Calculate the difference in days between each day and the previous one
df['Day_difference'] = df[1].diff().dt.days

# Check if the difference is in [2, 3]
df['Valid_difference'] = df['Day_difference'].isin([2, 3])

print(df)
```